# Как установить библиотеку brain.js?

Tags: javascript

Как установить эту библиотеку, и вообще, как устанавливать библиотеки в JavaScript?

Comment: script:src и всё

Comment: https://brain.js.org/#/getting-started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Библиотеки обычно устанавливаются в `<head>` html документа через следующий код:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
```

Здесь используется ссылка, которая каждый раз *подгружает* файл из интернета, ты можешь хранить файл библиотеки на своем сервере в `.minify` версии и вместо `external url` использовать локальную ссылку

То есть, для твоей либы, качаешь версию [отсюдаво](https://unpkg.com/brain.js), и прописываешь ей путь, как-то так:

```html
<script src="libs/brain-browser.min.js"></script>
```

(опять же, в head)

Comment: Скачал тот файл, закинул его туда же где и index.html, в head написал `<script src="brain-browser.min.js"></script> `, но получаю в консоль предупреждение о том что что-то не получилось установить (DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for file:///brain-browser.min.js.map: System error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) и в итоге ничего не работает. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: @abracatabra представь, что эта либа это город, а ошибка свидетельствует о том, что невозможно подгрузить карту `.map` для города, но город есть (короче либа должна работать, сейчас почти везде ошибки с мапами, но у тебя мапы просто нет, кинь рядом `файл.map`)

Comment: @abracatabra во вторых, твой скрипт должен лежать в `<body>` либо если он лежит в `<head>`, то инициализация после загрузки дома должна происходить, и в любом из двух кейсов - либа выше, чем твои скрипт, но ниже jquery, и слабее волка, но в цирке не выступает

Comment: а где достать этот .map файл?

Comment: @abracatabra соурс файл мап генерируется при сжатии, а т.е. должен быть доступен при скачивание архива либы... [нашел на их гите](https://github.com/BrainJS/brain.js/tree/master/dist)

Comment: Я скачал этот файл brain-browser.min.js.map, и засунул его рядом с brain-browser.min.js, но он всё равно не хочет работать и выдоёт всё то же предупреждение `DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for file:///brain-browser.min.js.map: System error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`  и не работает. Хотя я точно нигде не ошибся

Comment: @abracatabra это предупреждение, оно ни на что не должно влиять. Скорее всего неправильно работаешь с либой